# Query and Update deep child - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently stuck on how to query for deep nested child and then removing those children. A little bit of background:

In my app, users post jobs. The newly created job is posted to the jobs creator under: `jobs/serviceUsers/activeJobs/usersUID`

and also to the workers under: `jobs/workerUsers/workersUID`

[image: Database screenshot]

Now posting the jobs is no problem, but now I am stuck on what if the user wants to delete it? I have to delete it under serviceUsers (which is no problem) but also delete the job within workerUsers (Keep in mind there will be many workerUsers with the same jobID). So I need to query, find and delete those jobs.

I currently have this code to find the workers and expected it to work but nothing happened:

```
// jobID is the job to be deleted

let queryRef = firebase.database().ref(`/jobs/workerUsers`);

queryRef.orderByChild(jobID).equalTo(true).once('value', snap => {
  console.log('successful Query: ', snap.val);
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

(Note: this is my first time working with firebase)

Comment: While deleting the job from `serviceUsers` I assume you have the `usersUID`. So why can't you use it along with the `jobID` while deleting the job from `workerUsers`?

Comment: @VivekAthalye I do have it. 

There is one problem and it is that the JobID is nested under many workerUsers ID's that I DO NOT know of. In the screenshot you should image many other workerUsers UIDs that may or MAY NOT have the jobID nested within.

Comment: So if you have `usersUID` why not use `firebase.database().ref("/jobs/workerUsers/"+usersUID+"/"+jobID).remove();`? It won't delete the job from other users. Are you getting any error while doing this?

Comment: @VivekAthalye Sorry I got confused. I do not have the user ID's of the workerUsers who have the job nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments what I understand is: when a user deletes a job, you want to delete it from ALL worker users. If that is the case you will need to add 1 more node under jobs, something like `jobs/jobWorkers` which will have worker IDs mapped to job ID (like Haressh has suggested).

So your final structure will be like:

`jobs/serviceUsers/activeJobs/usersUID/jobId/{job details}` - listing of active job (if I understand correctly it will have the jobs details created by specific user)

`jobs/workerUsers/workersUID/jobId` - this will map different jobs a specific user (worker) is working on (No job details stored here)

`jobs/jobWorkers/jobId/workersUID` - this will map different workers working on a specific job (No job details stored here)

When a user tries to delete a job (created by him) first get the workers working on that job from `jobs/jobWorkers/jobId`, iterate on those worker IDs and remove the job ID from `jobs/workerUsers/<workerUID>/jobId`. Then delete the complete node @ `jobs/jobWorkers/jobId`. And then finally delete the complete node @ `jobs/serviceUsers/activeJobs/usersUID/jobId` that will delete job details as well.

Yes, there is some data duplication here. But that's normal. (Welcome to Firebase, and for that matter welcome to NoSql DB :) )

Read this if you haven't done it already: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!! I really appreciate it and understand what your concept is. You got everything right but there is one problem though: One worker is allowed to work on one job and no more than one. So the `jobs/jobWorkers` branch cant really exist. Furthermore, the actual job details existed under `jobs/workerUsers/workersUID/jobId/ { here are the details }`  because when the users opens the app he fetches this list of jobs so he can select from them. Otherwise he needs to query for the list of jobs right?

Comment: `job/jobWorkers` is going to store all workers' IDs working on a given job ID. So even if `One worker is allowed to work on one job and no more than one`, there are multiple workers working on same job, right? Also, in that case why are you having `workersUID/jobID` duplicated, under `serviceUsers` and `workerUsers`? One of them is redundant then, isn't it?

Comment: No, there are NO multiple workers working on the same job. Its like uber in the sense that 1 passenger - 1 driver.

The jobs that appear under `jobs/workerUsers/workersUID/jobId/{ job details }` are not jobs that the worker is working on, but the ones he can choose from.

Comment: Oh Boy!! Now I'm confused. Does that mean, the relation between job and workerUser is 1-1? At one point you say `Keep in mind there will be many workerUsers with the same jobID`. Then you say `workerUser's UID could be located under various JOB ID's`. Which gives an impression that the relation is M-N.... Why don't you detail out your business use case explaining the relationships between serviceUser / job / workerUser like 1-1, 1-M, M-N and who is creating job, how they are getting assigned to workers etc. That might give some clarity.

Comment: I have read your first response many times to understand it and I think I will implement it. Coming from SQL this is really a different approach. I want to thank you for being so cool by responding and helping me out.

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, coming from SQL background it feels a bit awkward :) until you get used to it :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155183/discussion-between-walter-monecke-and-vivek-athalye).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your problem correctly, from what i understood users create jobs under `jobs/serviceUsers/activeJobs/usersUID` which looks ok,

but when you create the same under  `jobs/workerUsers/workersUID` you instead need something like this `jobs/workerUsers/jobID/usersUID`

Then you can remove it like so
`firebase.database().ref("/jobs/workerUsers/"+jobID+"/"+usersUID).remove();`

Comment: Yes this would work, but this would take a different approach than mine.

If I follow this approach, then to display the jobs to the WORKERS I would also need to deep query, since a workerUser's UID could be located under various JOB ID's. One way or the other I will need to deep query somewhere and this is my current problem.